# phpmyadmin update exciting tables rows

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have an old database I switched over to the new hosting. Problem is, some of the data in the tables is corrupt due to bad moving. (used SSH to do it).

Lets talk about a table called postedithistory;
The data in the rows is missing some info, problem is I didnt notice it until people already did some editing and new rows has been entered into the table.

I want to move the old database again using PHPMYADMIN this time to the new hosting again.
This time, I'm moving only 1 table.

What I want is that phpmyadmin should update the existing old rows in the table, but should not delete or edit the new already existing rows.

How I do that with the options of "DROP TABLES", "DUMP function", and so on?

Comment: What I want is that phpmyadmin should update the existing old rows in the new table on the new database, but should not delete or edit the new already existing rows on the new table in the new database*

Comment: SOLVED: I think I managed to do it my removing the "drop table" option, and selecting "replace" on the Dump function.